# regex confusion on escape bracket in my case

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression :

```
\(.*\)
```

It matched all of this string.

```
(match this) but exclude this? (match this too)
```

but I expect it to match only the

```
(match this)
```

Why it doesn't exclude the text between (match this?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` is *greedy*, which means it will match as much as it can. You can use a non-greedy quantifier:

```
\(.*?\)
```

Or, alternatively:

```
\([^\)]*\)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\(.*?\)
```

use this.Use a non greedy modifier.